# Spring boot: javassist not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm starting with spring boot and I'm trying to write a small application coupled with an H2 in memory DB.
When I'm trying to run my application I've got **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.bytecode.ClassFile**
So I gueesed javassit jar was missing on the classpath. I started the application in debug mode and javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar is present in the classpath.
I'm certainly missing something but I can't figure out what.

here is the content of my POM file

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<!-- (you don't need this if you are using a .RELEASE version) -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

and this is my Application main class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and here is the stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJp
aAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.practice.songbook.Application.main(Application.java:17) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:85) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:167) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:78) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:725) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.
2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.REL
EASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.bytecode.ClassFile
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
```

adding a dependency to javassist doesn't solve the problem for info.

Comment: did you try using a release version ? you're using a build snapshot version.

Comment: Yes i've tried a release version. My example shows the last modiication I did but I was running with 1.3.0.RELEASE before.

Answer (score 9):

Its a problem with maven dependencies. Go to your .m2 folder and erase the folder of javassist. Then update your maven dependencies and it's gonna work. I had the same problem, and it works to me

Comment: in example: `C:\Users\Guest\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist`

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing this dependency:
              
              org.springframework.boot
              spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: no it's there. just before <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the issue.
I had the exact same issue when trying to run the springboot jpa sample and decided to clean my maven repository to start from scratch.
I works know. I'm not sure what was the initial problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You should add javassist as one of the dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>${javassist.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is the first thing I did but it didn't change anything.